# React native: How to do a "shared element/zoom" transition using navigator?

Tags: javascript, animation, react-native, navigator

Is it possible to make a "shared element/zoom" transition like [this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/7f54eba70b61f2f1ece5482f1eb89c72a12f5c43/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f72556b6b66555a2e676966) in react native using navigator?

Especially useful for something like image galleries/modals.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

Answer (score 4):

"Currently React doesn't support reusing a native view in different parts of the component hierarchy, which makes it difficult to implement shared element transitions in pure JS."

Checkout the below link:
https://github.com/brentvatne/hard-react-native-problems/issues/11

Additionally, It(Shared Element) may be roll-out in next version as part of Navigator. 
Check out the following thread:
https://twitter.com/intelligibabble/status/764162422831652865

Edit: airbnb launched native navigation with shared element transition to try. It not official yet. but can try out..
http://airbnb.io/native-navigation/docs/guides/shared-element-transitions.html

Update: It is worth to checkout https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation for shared element implementation.